# Is there a plugin used with C/C++ Eclipse IDE to make code suggestions and auto-complete automatically available?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Is there a plugin used with C/C++ Eclipse IDE to make code suggestions and auto-complete  available ?

I want this to be done without pressing Ctrl + Space every time.

Answer (score -1):

Window->Preferences->C/C++->Editor->Content Assist->Auto-Activation

If you are working on a big project, I do not recommend this feature as it could cause significant performance issues every time you type "." or "->" etc.

Comment: I'm looking for "Automatic" code suggestions. Things like when I type the first two letters of a variable's name a list will show up with valid options.
Your answer requires Ctrl + Space every time I want a code suggestion.
I've looked here and I found out that it is not an available feature in C/C++ editor 
So I'm looking for useful plugins I guess 
Thank your for your time and I appreciate your effort.